# Reservation form in jquery issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need some help to create a jquery script that will handle the car reservation form.

The form have fields such as the “Start date, End date (in datepicker), localization (city) of rent and return the car and the number of days for which the customer borrowed car. There is only one dependency. If the car is rented for less than 4 days the city of borrowing and returning must be the same, and if the number of days are greater than 4 days locations of returning car may be different.

The whole form works pretty well, to the point where the client starts to manipulate the date of return, to live the car in other city and rent a car for less then 4 days.

The workin example: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/W7NHK/48/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be like this?

```
if ( parseInt($("#finish_day").val()) < 4 ) {
    $('#return_car')
        .children('#return_car option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']')
        .attr('selected', true)
        .siblings().attr('disabled', true);
}
```